# Get matching elements' values in two arrays

Tags: python, arrays

If `a` and `b` were lists of objects, each with a name property (e.g. `a1 = A("1")`, `b1 = B("1")`, etc.), how would I check for equivalency? I'm currently doing this:

```
aList = [ a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 ]
bList = [ b1, b2 ]
aNameList = []
bNameList = []

for i in aList:
    aNameList.append( i.name )
for i in bList:
    bNameList.append( i.name )

match = set(aNameList) & set(bNameList)

>>> set(['1', '2'])
```

But it seems kind of long and unnecessary. What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions instead to replace those temporary lists and for-loops of your example:

```
match = set( [ x.name for x in aList ] ) & set ( [ x.name for x in bList ] )
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, your right... time for me to go bed (for future readers, I deleted my comment)

Comment: `set` will accept a generator, so the square brackets are unnecessary.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Would the square brackets be stylistically better or just completely unnecessary in general?

Comment: I would consider it stylistically better to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

The [operator.attrgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) function was designed for extracting fields of interest:

```
set(map(attrgetter('name'), aList)) & set(map(attrgetter('name'), bList))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the list comprehension (replacing the temporary lists and for loop) with map
like:

```
name = lambda: n: n[name]
match = set(map(name,aList))&set(map(name,bList))
```